# Simplify$ [(ABC)' + (B' + C)']'$

Tags: logic

Need help on how to simplify $[(ABC)' + (B' + C)']'$.

Here is my attempt:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&[(ABC)' + (B' + C)']'\\
&=&(ABC) + (B' + C)\\
&=&B'+C(AB + 1)\\
&=&B' + ABC
\end{eqnarray}

Is this correct? What can I do next?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't apply DeMorgan's Law correctly; you must flip the $+$ to a $\times$ (using concatenation). You should obtain:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
[(ABC)' + (B' + C)']'
&=&(ABC)''(B' + C)''\\
&=&(ABC)(B' + C)\\
&=&(ABC)B' + (ABC)C\\
&=&A(BB')C + AB(CC)\\
&=&A(0)C + AB(C)\\
&=&0 + ABC\\
&=&ABC\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$